# Is there a way to make audio processing done with the Web Audio Api downloadable?

Tags: audio, download, html5-audio

I want to be able to download a new audio file that includes the processing from the Web Audio API.

Comment: Have you checked out recorder.js? I'm pretty sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I have found recorder.js, but this tool seems to be used to record audio from the existing microphone. I am trying to process existing audio and save the output to a disk:

upload audio file from computer -> process with tools from the js web api -> download file back to computer. 

It would be a huge plus if the tool in question is capable of doing this faster than realtime as well.

Comment: recorder.js can record any audio stream that you pipe into an analyser node. It's not just for microphone input. You might also want to look into the offlineAudioContext if you want faster-than-realtime audio processing.